# Problems with building this regex [1,2,3]

Tags: java, regex

i have a problem to build following regex:
[1,2,3,4]

i found a work-around, but i think its ugly

```
String stringIds = "[1,2,3,4]";
stringIds = stringIds.replaceAll("\\[", ""); 
stringIds = stringIds.replaceAll("\\]", "");
String[] ids = stringIds.split("\\,");
```

Can someone help me please to build one regex, which i can use in the split function
Thanks for help

edit:
i want to get from this string "[1,2,3,4]" to an array with 4 entries. the entries are the 4 numbers in the string, so i need to eliminate "[","]" and ",". the "," isn't the problem.
the first and last number contains [ or ]. so i needed the fix with replaceAll. But i think if i use in split a regex for ",", i also can pass a regex which eliminates "[" "]" too. But i cant figure out, who this regex should look like.

Comment: Doesn't Java have a join method?

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what you want. First you say you want the regex `[1,2,3,4]` (but it really doesn't look much like a regex; what exactly is it you want?), then you say `String stringIDs = [1,2,3,4];` (which doesn't look to me as if it will even compile), and then the rest of the code makes it look as if what you're actually after is a list of strings containing "1", "2", and so on. (But from what input?) For the sake of other readers who are as stupid as I am, could you please clarify *exactly* what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MarkLinus AFAIK, the standard libraries don't have a Ruby-like join() method.  Sadly.

Comment: +1 for the OP realizing something is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: sorry, forgot the " in this version. its only a excerpt.

Comment: my goal ist to get from this string "[1,2,3]" to an int array with 3 entries 1 2 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost what you're looking for:

```
    String q = "[1,2,3,4]";
    String[] x = q.split("\\[|\\]|,");
```

The problem is that it produces an extra element at the beginning of the array due to the leading open bracket.  You may not be able to do what you want with a single regex sans shenanigans.  If you *know* the string always begins with an open bracket, you can remove it first.

The regex itself means "(split on) any open bracket, OR any closed bracket, OR any comma."

Punctuation characters frequently have additional meanings in regular expressions.  The double leading backslashes... ugh, the first backslash tells the Java String parser that the next backslash is not a special character (example: \n is a newline...) so `\\` means "I want an honest to God backslash".  The next backslash tells the regexp engine that the *next* character (`[` for example) is *not* a special regexp character. That makes me lol.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe substring `[` and `]` from beginning and end, then split the rest by `,`

```
String stringIds = "[1,2,3,4]";
String[] ids = stringIds.substring(1,stringIds.length()-1).split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're trying to make an array (not sure where you got 'regex' from; that means something different). In this case, you want:

```
String[] ids = {"1","2","3","4"};
```

If it's specifically an array of integer numbers you want, then instead use:

```
int[] ids = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: I'm unsure. Edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not amenable to splitting by delimiter. It is much safer and more general to split by matching the integers themselves:

```
static String[] nums(String in) {
  final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(in);
  final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (m.find()) l.add(m.group());
  return l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums("[1, 2, 3, 4]")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first line your code is following:

```
String stringIds = "[1,2,3,4]";
```

and you're trying to iterate over all number items, then the follwing code-frag only could work:

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\b", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```