# Extract text from two different types of chars using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract strings from a text that features two different types of characters.
The characters are `|` and `#` and the text is coming from an outside source.

I will give you an example:

- Input: `#hello|#what|whatsup|` should return `hello|` and `whatsup`.
- Input: `#hello#` should return `hello`
- Input: `|ola|1` should return `ola`
- Input: `|hello#|what#whatsup#node` should return `hello#` and `whatsup`

Comment: Post your code and we'll help.

Comment: Thanks @TonyEnnis, I'm too weak at this. I know that if I write `Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#")` then I can use it to extract text that is surrounded by `#`, but I don't know how to do it with two different chars .

Comment: What is the expected output of "#||##||MiddleRecursion||##||#"? Note the symmetry.

Comment: @nhahtdh I should return `||##||MiddleRecursion||##||` in that case.

Comment: Ok, well, if you _try_, we'll help you get up to speed.  Here's a good place to start - read through this similar discussion from earlier today.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766192/problems-with-building-this-regex-1-2-3/10766412#10766412

Comment: @TonyEnnis yes, I'm afraid I have to. But even if I didn't had to, I would really like to know how it is done using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your strings. I don't know if I completely understood what you need, but I think it can be tuned if necessary:

```
     String s1 = "#hello|#what|whatsup|";
     String s2 = "#hello#";
     String s3 = "|ola|1";
     String s4 = "|hello#|what#whatsup#node";

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\w)+)(\\||#)(\\||#)?");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s4);
     while(matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + (matcher.group(4) != null ? matcher.group(4).equals("|")? "#" : "|" : ""));
         matcher.find(); //to jump over the next match
     }
```

Update:
I just read the middlerecursion example. Doesn't work for that, I'm afraid, and I have to leave my computer for a while. So this is just something to get you started.

Update version that works for all the examples:

```
     String s1 = "#hello|#what|whatsup|";
     String s2 = "#hello#";
     String s3 = "|ola|1";
     String s4 = "|hello#|what#whatsup#node";
     String s5 = "#||##||MiddleRecursion||##||#";

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#|\\|)((#|\\|)*\\w+(#|\\|)*)(#|\\|)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
     while(matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
     }
```

Comment: If I change the order of the | and # in middle recursion example, the result might not be "correct". e.g. `#||##||MiddleRecursion|#|#||#`. Anyway, I don't know what is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `#||##||MiddleRecursion||##||#` --> `||##||MiddleRecursion||##||`, I'm afraid you have to do bracket matching. In this case, there will be no general solution using regex (you can force it to work if you know the maximum consecutive appearance of | and #). The reason is that, there is middle recursion; regular expression can only solves left or right recursion.

This is also **one** of the reasons why HTML parsing is not possible with regex.

Comment: The 'middle recursion' example isn't part of the question.  It's possible the instructor left it off for this reason.

Comment: There must be an expected answer. At least from the instructor or from the person who write the program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll start.

So you have to match #something# or |something|

Can you write two separate regexps that do that?

Where you'll get annoyed first is that the pipe `|` is a magic character in regexp.  If you want to match on that character, you'll have to prefix it with `\\` as per the other thread I linked.

When you have those two regexp working, let me know and I'll post more.

(I'm heading out for a few hours...)

Comment: Instead of prefixing `|` with `\\\`, I would suggest to use [Pattern.quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)